# Composite key in Spring boot more than 16 columns

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have working with MySQL, Spring Boot & JPA . I want to generate a table that have **composite primary on 18 Columns** of Dto class.Total 40 variable/columns in class

`CompositeKeys.java`

```
public class CompositeKeys implements Serializable {
    private int column1;
    private String column2;
            .
            .
            .
    private int column18;
```

`Domain.java`

```
@IdClass(CompositeKeys.class)
@Table(name = "table")
public class Domain implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int column1;
    @Id
    private int column2;
            .
            .
            .
     @Id
     private int column18;
     private String column40;
```

> Error 
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Too many key parts specified; max 16 parts allowed
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]

Please guide me how to solve out this. If i create the table manually on SQL Server and create the table using query than it will allow me to create this . I want to create table using Domain

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support more than 16 columns in a key (search for "An index may consist of up to 16 columns" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).
**Hence it's not possible with MySQL**

Comment: Sir I want to apply **MUL** on all keys and **PRI** on **cloumn1**. This is being performed while i alter table using terminal .

Comment: reference to this article I want to apply **MUL** key .https://www.tutorialspoint.com/create-mysql-column-with-key-mul

Comment: I don't want to apply the **PRI** keys for all 16 . I just want **PRI** for one attribute and **MUL** for other

Comment: Hm, but your question states you want to create a primary key on 18 columns.
Anyway according to MySQL doc (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-columns.html) MUL is also an index and so a limitation of 16 columns is valid for it too.
This limitation is very good. Usually there is no need to have many columns in a single index.

Comment: If you want to be within 16 columns limit, then I don't think there is a separate entity for MUL index in Spring Data and JPA. But on the top of my head MUL is non unique index, we can use unique field (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html#unique--) for Index annotation to define non unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your entity implementation and your comment to the other answer you do NOT want a composite primary key, but you want a simple primary key AND a composite index.

Try this:

```
@Table(name = "table", indexes = { @Index( name="index", columnList="column2, ... ,column18" ) } )
public class Domain implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int column1;

    private int column2;
            .
            .
            .
    private int column18;
    private String column40;
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index on table "column2, ... ,column18" )"

Comment: I assume the 16 column rule still applies. Try to remove one column from the index.